# JTree: Return branch when leaf selected

Tags: jtree

I am new to JTrees and have a simple question.  If I select a leaf, I can return the selected row number by using

```
int row = getRowForPath(getSelectionPath());
```

Is there a way to return the path/row for the branch under which my leaf falls?  That is, if I have the following tree:

- Root

  - Fruit

    - Apple
    - Banana
  - Vegetable

    - Lettuce
    - Carrot

And I select "Apple", then I get the row number for "Fruit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke [`getParentPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getParentPath--) on the result returned by `getSelectionPath()`.

```
tree.getSelectionPath().getParentPath()
```

Because [`getPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getPath--) "returns an ordered array of the elements of this TreePath," the penultimate element of the resulting array is the parent. You can see the effect in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260104/230513); a `TreeSelectionListener` updates a `JTextField` as shown  below.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the method I needed. Thanks!